# Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(editorState: EditorState) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building rich text editor using react with typescript But I am getting error which I have attached in the snapshot and also I have pasted my EditorState.tsx code
[image]

So could you please let me know why I am getting this error

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {EditorState} from "draft-js";
import {Editor} from "react-draft-wysiwyg";

type MyProps = {
}

type MyState = {
    editorState:any
}

class EditorContainer extends Component<MyProps,MyState>{
    constructor(props:MyProps){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      };
    }
  
    onEditorStateChange: Function = (editorState:any) => {
      // console.log(editorState)
      this.setState({
        editorState,
      });
    };
  
    render(){
      const { editorState } = this.state;
      return <div className='editor'>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}    
          toolbar={{
            inline: { inDropdown: true },
            list: { inDropdown: true },
            textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
            link: { inDropdown: true },
            history: { inDropdown: true },
            // image: { uploadCallback: uploadImageCallBack, alt: { present: true, mandatory: true } },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
onEditorStateChange: Function = (editorState:any) => {
```

You've given this the type `Function`, which means it could be literally any function. Then when you try to pass the function into the editor, typescript is pointing out that only specific functions are allowed, not any function.

Instead, do:

```
onEditorStateChange = (editorState: EditorState) => {
  this.setState({
    editorState,
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working fine now :)

Comment: @Abhishekkumar please dont forget to accept the answer